# How can I increase the value of a Firestore subcollection-document-field?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So, I am working on an Android app and what I try to do is to increase the value of a field by 1, by pressing a button. Basically, I have a collection of users, each of them having a subcollection of posts, each post having a numeric field called 'applicants' which I use to count how many persons applied to a job.

The problem is I can't find a way to query the exact document field because I can't obtain the documents ID programmatically. I have been trying to identify the post by searching for its title but no luck. When I run the code it doesn't throw any error, the app doesn't crash, but still, nothing changes in my database.

This is my database structure:

[image: Database Structure]

```
public void executeTransaction(int position){
        db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {

                db.collectionGroup("posts").whereEqualTo("title", list.get(position).getTheTitle()).get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                DocumentReference postRef = usersRef.document("posts");
                                DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = null;
                                try {
                                    postSnapshot = transaction.get(postRef);
                                } catch (FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                long newApplicants = postSnapshot.getLong("applicants") + 1;
                                transaction.update(postRef, "applicants", newApplicants);
                            }
                        });
                return null;
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You have applied to this job!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

This is the method that runs when you tap the "Apply" button. The argument 'position' is just the position the post is stored in a local `ArrayList<Post> list`.

How can I simply increase the `applicants` value of a post?

Comment: Can you obtain the `userId` programmatically?

Comment: @GauravMall yes, my userId and the poster's userId as well

Comment: Why can't you obtain the post's id programmatically? The way you have it organized is supposed to able to give you the post. Can you tell us how do you save the post?

Comment: I can't find any way to get it's ID. I have an ArrayList<Post>list where I save the posts I read from Firestore, this way:
```
 for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : documentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                            Post post = new Post();
                            post.setTitle(documentSnapshot.getString("title"));
                            post.setApplicants(documentSnapshot.getLong("applicants"));
                            ...
                            list.add(post);
                        }
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Check my answer now, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) (click this to go to the documentation). Basically, how they work is detailed in the documentation:

> Using the Cloud Firestore client libraries, you can group multiple operations into a single transaction. **Transactions are useful when you want to update a field's value based on its current value, or the value of some other field.**

And you are using a transaction the correct way, but not in the best case. As you want to update only one value transactions could be an overload of work for your database. A simple increment method will do the work using [FieldValue.increment()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#public-static-fieldvalue-increment-double-l):

```
DocumentReference postRef = db.collection("users").document(userId).collection("posts").document(postId);

// Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
washingtonRef.update("applicants", FieldValue.increment(50));
```

You need to have the id of the post you want to update.

To solve the problem you are having just edit your `Post` class and add this:

```
string id;

public void setId(string id) {
   this.id = id;
}

public string getId() {
   return id; 
}
```

And when you get the posts just do this (aka. how to get the post id):

```
for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : documentSnapshots.getDocuments()) { 
    Post post = new Post(); 
    post.setId(documentSnapshot.getId());
    post.setTitle(documentSnapshot.getString("title")); 
    post.setApplicants(documentSnapshot.getLong("applicants")); ... list.add(post); 
} 
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And when updating the `applicants` field, to obtain the documents ID just do:

```
string postId = post.getId();
```

then continue with your normal code.

Comment: Hello! I've been trying this way too, but I get to the same problem.. how am i supposed to find the posts id? that's the main problem here..

Comment: Sorry mate, but you just don't get it. I can't find any possible way to get the post's id (the document's id).

Comment: I just provided you the way to get the post's Id

Comment: I don't want to be rude or something, but you clearly don't get it. You provided me a way to get the post's instance id, but to have the post's id stored in the instance of post class, first you have to get the autogenerated id from firestore. Like when I create a new post, that id parameter has to get it's value from the documents name. I found out that annotating the parameter with @DocumentId might solve this. I'll let you know how it worked.

Comment: Uhm yeah, I really don't get it. What do you mean the id parameter has to get its value from the document's name? By the way, if you don't understand what I'm doing: basically loading the posts into the same list as you, then when the person clicks apply, we get the index of the post, get the id from the class and then increment the `applicants` value. When getting the list, we just get the id of the document from the snapshot. Are you sure you are showing the whole database structure? If you found anything else report it :)

Comment: So, please, think out of android stuido. Just database related. Firestore generates IDs for every document in it's database. In collection Posts we'll have a bunch of documents (of type post) with autogenerated IDs that look like "km2CGotkxTlDKA2hoh0Z". Now, inside our post document, we have a bunch of fields like: title, description, id (now that you suggested it) etc. How am I supposed to store "km2CGotkxTlDKA2hoh0Z" in the ID field?

Comment: No, I did not run it because it doesn't solve my problem. Indeed, you had a good idea, I know what you are trying to tell me and belive me I totally understood it.

Comment: No, no, no you got the wrong impression. What I'm advising is to get the autogenerated ID in the ID field in your java class. Don't have any id field inside your post document in the database. Just have the id stored in the class, not in the database. Hope you understand.

Comment: Ok than. How can you do that? I can't find any possible way to manipulate the autogenerated id.

Comment: When you load the posts in the list, every time just get the autogenerated id of the post and store it in the class by using `documentsnapshot.getId()`. This function will give you the autogenerated id.

Comment: If this is possible I'm going to throw myself out the window. Brb

Comment: Just try the code a bit and if it doesn't work try to work out the problem. I'm not trying to be rude, just trying to help you/

Comment: It really worked! Thank you very much man! You saved me. Sorry for my wooden-head, but not knowing about this .getId() method made me understand that you suggest something else.

Comment: You can be sure! In fact this is my first visible "vote up". Stack just badged me. Happy coding mate!